# What kind of grammar construction is this?

Tags: past-perfect, gerunds, infinitives, to-infinitive

I came across this sentence in "English Grammar In Use Supplementary Exercises".
The following sentence is:

***"We had hoped to be living (live) in our new house by now, but the builders are still working on it".***

I have never came across usage of both past perfect and to be + ing, therefore, it is confusing to me :)

Comment: What's confusing about it? What parts of it do you already understand? Please show us that you've made some effort to understand it yourself so we can meet you half way. :)

Comment: I just don't understand had + -ed + to be + -ing construction because I have never seen it, and I don't know when and how I should use this.

Comment: Are you familiar with *past perfect*? Are you familiar with *"hope to" + verb*? Are you familiar with *continuous* grammar? This isn't a single structure. This is those three things combined

Comment: When work started on the house, the owners said "We shall be living in it by July." Now it is July and the house is not finished. They _had hoped_ that they would be living in it by now (but they can't hope for that any more).